# JavaScript ES6: What is this feature called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Q: Does anyone know what this JavaScript ES6 feature is called? It's a technique of applying a prefix to identified names. Like this:

```
var { Router,
Route,
IndexRoute,
IndexLink,
hashHistory,
Link } = ReactRouter;
```

It saves me having to write long code. Example:

I can write this in React:

```
<Route path="/acc"          component={CLAccounts} />
<Route path="/acc/:year"        component={CLAccounts} />
<Route path="/acc/:year/:month"     component={CLAccounts} />
```

Instead of this:

```
<ReactRouterRoute path="/acc"           component={CLAccounts} />
<ReactRouterRoute path="/acc/:year"     component={CLAccounts} />
<ReactRouterRoute path="/acc/:year/:month"  component={CLAccounts} />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This has nothing to do with "prefixes". The proper "long" syntax would be `ReactRouter.Route` (not `ReactRouterRoute`), which is simple property access

Comment: It was in an article expressly to show how to save typing. ie: prefixing.
Maybe it's just using the syntax in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

This is called destructuring. It's super useful!!

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks. Destructuring seems to have more to do with breaking apart an array into separate vars. There's no data here per se, just a way to prefix variables. Anyway, very useful to save typing.